# Flutter - Can't compile Android SDK 34, compiles SDK 33 instead

Tags: android, flutter

I am trying to build an app release with Android SDK 34 as TargetSDK. I am also setting my compileSdkVersion to 34 in the android build.gradle

````
   ```defaultConfig {
    // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
    applicationId "com.app.android"
    // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
    // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-build-configuration.
    minSdkVersion 25
    compileSdkVersion 34
    targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
    multiDexEnabled true
}```
````

But, after uploading it to the play store it shows, that my target sdk is SDK33 and not SDK34.
[image]

My app is also not working with smartphones using SDK 34. Flutter Doctor shows no problems, I have downloaded the SDK 34 within android studio.

What can i do?

Answer (score 1):

You don't target SDK version 34. Flutter constants are defined [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/src/main/groovy/flutter.groovy), and currently, `flutter.targetSdkVersion` is set to 33 in the latest release.

If you want to explicitly target SDK version 34, you have to set it manually:

```
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 25
    compileSdkVersion 34
    targetSdkVersion 34 // Change this line
    ...
}
```